# Does this question add value to SO?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question

Several months ago I asked the following question:

[Cmake cannot find QGLWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812161/cmake-cannot-find-qglwidget)

I did all the right things before asking: tried to solve it myself, searched StackOverflow and the internet at large for existing answers etc. (I didn't provide a complete MCVE, but did give all the cmake code, which was where I thought the problem lay, and posted the error I got)

By the time I asked the question, I had inadvertently introduced a typo to my code that disguised the actual fix to my problem (installing qt-sdk on my machine). I explained this in a comment to the answer, but I have been wondering recently if this question should be closed as off-topic for the following reason:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

I hesitate to do it because the question is still getting regular page views, and I do summarize some of the common culprits to the problem, but that doesn't change the fact that my question was a simple typographical error. So should this question be closed, or left to stay?

Comment: It looks like a fair question. Not sure if anyone will ever again bump into the same issue, but I see no reason to remove it. Then again, I am almost new here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a Qt expert but my guess is the page views are caused by people searching for `Qt cmake QGLWidget` because build errors when using those classes seems imminent.

If you agree on that your question is indeed nothing more then a typo and I doubt if most viewers of that question actually find your question helpful.

Nobody of the 238 viewers cared to upvote your question and only 3 found the answer useful.

We don't loose much value if your question gets closed and/or deleted.